# Convert the TimeStamp from an API to local TimeStamp

Tags: java, timestamp

I need a help with the code. 
My API has TimeStamp in UTC format and I need to convert it to my local TimeStamp i.e., CST.

For example: 
MY API has TimeStamp value as : 2019-01-08T13:17:53.4225514   (which is in UTC).

I need the output to be like Jan 8, 2019 8:28:18.514 AM  (Which is in CST my local Time )

How to convert it in local TimeStamp?

Timestamp createdOn = api.getCreatedOn(); (HERE I get the TimeStamp as Object from api)

Comment: The last line is confusing. Do you get the time stamp as a String "2019-01-08T13:17:53.4225514" or do you get it as a java.sql.Timestamp object? (Which does not provide information about time zones.)

Comment: @kumesana I get the TimeStamp as 2019-01-08T13:17:53.4225514 value in JSON and I store it in a TimeStamp Object.

Comment: Please don't use class Timestamp as it is obsolete. Use LocalDateTime. As for the conversion required, first parse the String with a DateTimeFormatter setup to use time zone UTC, then convert the LocalDateTime so obtained to a LocalDateTime in CST zone.

Comment: @kumesana I tried, but not working. Can you help me with codesnippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a bit difficult to do right after all.

Here's how you parse a String timestamp in UTC to obtain a ZonedDateTime object of your preferred time zone:

```
// define formatter once to be re-used wherever needed
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") // all fields up seconds
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true) // handle variable-length fraction of seconds
        .toFormatter();

String text = "2019-01-08T13:17:53.4225514";

LocalDateTime localTime = LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter); // parse string as a zone-agnostic LocalDateTime object
ZonedDateTime utcTime = localTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")); // make it zoned as UTC zoned
ZonedDateTime cstTime = utcTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")); // convert that date to the same time in CST

// print resulting objects
System.out.println(utcTime);
System.out.println(cstTime);
```